# Oracle SQL - Get difference between dates based on check in and checkout records

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume I have the following table data.

```
#  |  USER  |  Entrance |  Transaction Date Time
-----------------------------------------------
1  |  ALEX  |  INBOUND  |  2020-01-01  10:20:00
2  |  ALEX  |  OUTBOUND |  2020-01-02  10:00:00
3  |  ALEX  |  INBOUND  |  2020-01-04  11:30:00
4  |  ALEX  |  OUTBOUND |  2020-01-07  15:00:00
5  |  BEN   |  INBOUND  |  2020-01-08  08:00:00
6  |  BEN   |  OUTBOUND |  2020-01-09  09:00:00
```

I would like to know the total of how many days the user has stay outbound.

For each inbound and outbound is considered one trip, every trip exceeded 24 hours is considered as 2 days.

Below is my desired output:

```
No. of Days   |   Trips Count
----------------------------------
Stay < 1 day  |   1
Stay 1 day    |   1
Stay 2 days   |   0
Stay 3 days   |   0
Stay 4 days   |   1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is a trip < 1 day?

Comment: @user9601310 I have try to visualize it on a piece of paper but I don't have an idea how to construct the query.

Comment: @Turo Trip < 1 day means stay less than 24 hours.

Comment: 2 days means > 24 houers and 1 day is exactly 24h ? You sorted trip 1 to 1 day in the example. My guess after some thinking: inbound day = outbound day?

Comment: @Turo 2 days means > 48 hours but < 72 hours, so < 1 days means < 24 hours.

Comment: Then PLEASE correct your Question and the expected result!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223625/discussion-between-turo-and-javatar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `lead()` and aggregation.  Assuming that the rows are properly interlaced:

```
select floor( (next_dt - dt) ) as num_days, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lead(dt) over (partition by user order by dt) as next_dt
      from trips t
     ) t
where entrance = 'INBOUND'
group by floor( (next_dt - dt) )
order by num_days;
```

Note:  This does not include the `0` rows.  That does not seem central to your question and is a significant complication.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got inspired from it.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what you mean with < 1 day, but this I got this far

**Setup**

```
create table trips (id number, name varchar2(10), entrance varchar2(10), ts TIMESTAMP); 
insert into trips values( 1  ,  'ALEX','INBOUND', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 10:20:00');
insert into trips values(2  ,  'ALEX','OUTBOUND',TIMESTAMP '2020-01-02 10:00:00');
insert into trips values(3  ,  'ALEX','INBOUND',TIMESTAMP '2020-01-04 11:30:00');
insert into trips values(4  ,  'ALEX','OUTBOUND',TIMESTAMP '2020-01-07  15:00:00');
insert into trips values(5  ,  'BEN','INBOUND',TIMESTAMP '2020-01-08 08:00:00');
insert into trips values(6  ,  'BEN','OUTBOUND',TIMESTAMP '2020-01-09 07:00:00');
```

**Query**

```
select decode (t.days, 0 , 'Stay < 1 day', 1, 'Stay 1 day', 'Stay ' || t.days ||  ' days') Days , count(d.days) Trips_count
FROM (Select Rownum - 1  days From dual Connect By Rownum <= 6) t   left join
(select  extract (day from b.ts - a.ts) + 1 as days from trips a
inner join trips b on a.name = b.name 
and a.entrance = 'INBOUND' 
and b.entrance = 'OUTBOUND' 
and a.ts < b.ts 
and not exists (select ts from trips where entrance = 'OUTBOUND' and ts > a.ts and ts < b.ts)) d
on t.days = d.days
group by t.days order by t.days
```

**Result**

```
DAYS            | TRIPS_COUNT
----------------|------------
Stay < 1 day    | 0
Stay 1 day      | 2
Stay 2 days     | 0
Stay 3 days     | 0
Stay 4 days     | 1
Stay 5 days     | 0
```

You could replace the 6 with a select max with the second subquery repeated

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think it would be intensive as my table will be very huge.

Comment: With the right index it wouldn't be that terrible, but I myself voted for @Gordon's answer